# Flashing Qualcomm AOSP Images error: Checking product... FAILED

Tags: android, android-source, qualcomm

I have successfully build images for **Qualcomm Snapdragon 845 board** using Qualcomm chipcode.

Now I am trying to flash those images using on **Intrinsyc OpenQ845 board** using `fastboot flashall -w` command. But I am getting error:

> Checking product...
>
> FAILED
>
> Device Product is 'Open-Q_845'
>
> Update requires 'sdm845'

Any idea what I might be doing wrong or workaround to do this. This board had preinstalled Android 9 in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that we need to flash all images individually so flashall wont work, hope it help somebody. Alternatively you can use Jflash to flash your images which works better.

Comment: Yes, AOSP can be get from CAF https://wiki.codeaurora.org/xwiki/bin/QAEP/release & CHipcode can be get from https://createpoint.qti.qualcomm.com if you have license

Comment: do you have licence , I need some camera files